# Change format of phone number field in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table with an imported phone number field that accidentally was imported in the format `NNN-NNNN-NNN`.  I would like to change any phone numbers in that format to the format `NNN-NNN-NNNN`.  The fields that I want to test for the invalid format (and update if incorrect) can be identified with the following query:

```
SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 9
```

Can anyone advise how to do make the change?

Comment: Which part of this task presents a difficulty and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RLIKE` to select the values that need to be modified, and `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `REPLACE` to modify:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET phone_number = 
    CONCAT(
        LEFT(phone_number, 7),
        '-',
        REPLACE(RIGHT(phone_number, 5), '-', '')
    )
WHERE phone_number RLIKE '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/52MVDe7LGg6wHgaLUcWuku/0)**

Original data:

```
| phone_number |
| ------------ |
| 012-3456-789 |
| 987-654-3210 |
```

After running the update statement:

```
| phone_number |
| ------------ |
| 012-345-6789 |
| 987-654-3210 |
```